# Display data from state with React Typescript

Tags: typescript, database, api, axios

I managed to get data from api with axios and locate it in react state but can't figure it out how to display it in web to be able to list whole data that im getting from my api get request.
I have tried map function etc but every time it's not displaying or showing error.

below is my code and data that i managed to get from server.

```
import axios from "axios"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"


function AdministrationPanel() {
  const [inqueries, getInqueries] = useState<any[]>([])
  const token ="**************************************************"
  const url = "https://strapi-km.herokuapp.com/api/inquiries?populate=*"

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(url, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const InqueriesData = response.data
        console.log(InqueriesData)
        getInqueries(InqueriesData)
      })
  }, [])
  console.log(inqueries)
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {this.state.inqueries.map(({ name }: any) => {
          return <p>{name}</p>
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default AdministrationPanel
```

[My data response in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kcMe.png)

[My app state data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbFCQ.png)

I was trying every solution that I managed to find but since im totally new to programming I cannot solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the absence of a token, I can't surely say that this is the final solution, maybe your response type will be different, however, the issue is that you are accessing `inqueries` incorrectly. You shouldn't use `this.state`, because you are using a function component, which has no `this.state`.
To fix the issue you should directly use the `inqueries` variable as follows:

```
 <div>
        {inqueries.map(({ name }: any) => {
          return <p>{name}</p>
        })}
 </div>
```

Also, I would advise you to rename `getInqueries` to `setInqueries`, since it is just setting the state not getting

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. For sure will rename getInguiries but unfortunately after trying your solution im getting 'Inquiries.map is not a function
TypeError: inquiries.map is not a function' error ... :(  I can see in the internet that its due to fact that Objects, '{}' in JavaScript do not have the method '.map().' cause its only for arrays but im totally lost and dont know how to solve that problem with ts.

Comment: Saw that you have the response in the description. Just change the thing that you set. Use `setInqueries(InqueriesData.data)`

Comment: Also, you don't have the `name` directly. You have `attributes`. To access the name you should use  `{inqueries.map(({ attributes}) => attributes.name)`

Comment: Omg finally it f*****g works !!! :D Thanks a lot really ! Also right now I can clearly understand what was my mistake and definitely in the future will look closer how data that i am trying to display looks and base on that should better create map function. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I having the same problem while trying display photos from that API. I trying to solve it like i have learnt thanks to you but don't know exactly how to map that photos array data that's inside attributes. Everything else im displaying without any problem but because uploaded photos  are like one array inside attributes i cannot map it and display. Could you somehow try help or explain how can I achieve it ?

Comment: I suggest you to include the code here or open a question and ping me

Comment: `<p>attributes.photos.data.map(id) => {
         return (  <p> {id}</p> ) }}</p> `  [and here is data screen that im trying to access] 
(https://imgupx.com/lGERDdki)

Comment: Image not found and the code snippet has errors. Try this:
`<p className="py-2 pl-7 mb-2  bg-gray-50 text-gray-900 text-xs border-black border font-light">{attributes.photos.data.map((id) => (<p> {id}</p>))}</p>`

Comment: right now img link should be fine. Unfortunately with provided answer i got error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

Comment: your error means that `attributes.photos.data` is  null, consider using `attributes.photos.data?.map()`